# conversion to string with std::stringstream fails on white spaces

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert any string or character or number to `std::string` with `std::stringstream`. This is what I am doing:

```
template<typename T>
std::string toString(T a){
    std::string s;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss <<a;
    ss >>s;
    return s;
    }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char s[100]="I am a string with spaces";
    std::cout<<toString(s);

    return 0;
}
```

But it fails on the first white space.

Output:

```
I
```

Expected Ouput:

```
I am a string with spaces
```

How can I do this.

Note: `s` can contain newline character too.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki you should make that an answer so that I can accept it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly access the stringified content of a stream with the [`std::ostringstream::str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) member function.

```
template <typename T>
std::string toString(const T& a)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    //   ↑
    ss << a;
    return ss.str();
    //     ~~~~~~~^
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f34fe74e4a86845)

Comment: Downvoted. No explanation of the problem whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

`operator<<` has no problem inserting `s` into the stringstream. It's no different than if you did `std::cout << s`. What you're doing wrong is extracting from the stream into `s`. This will only read up to a whitespace character (which includes both spaces and newlines.) To get the contents of the stream, do:

```
return ss.str();
```

This however is just a convoluted way of doing:

```
std::string str = s;
```

Just reduce your entire program by 10 lines:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char s[100]="I am a string with spaces";
    std::cout<<std::string(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jahid That's not what your question asked, though

Comment: Notice the part that says `I am trying to convert any string or character or number`

Comment: What about `std::to_string`?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use stringstream, then there is one of possible solutions:
(I do not pretend to have a good code)

```
template<typename T>
std::string toString(T a) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << a;
    const char* s = ss.str().c_str();
    ss.read((char *)s, ss.str().length());
    return s;
}
```